# Can you rewire a remote controlled ceiling fan to not be remote controlled?

Tags: ceiling-fan, rewire

I have a 9 year old $750 ceiling fan (that is now $1600 to purchase new) that used to work with an in wall remote control that communicated to a chip inside the fan to control the light and speeds.  American Home Shield contracted electrician said they no longer could communicate with each other (remote & chip) so they replaced it with a cheap one which is all AHS would cover and the wall remote was lost in the process.  Because that original fan matches all my other light fixtures, I'd like to know if that ceiling fan can be rewired to just turn on and off from a wall switch - I don't even care about speeds or the lighting feature.

Comment: Without having a schematic of the fan, all we can say is "probably". Giving us make and model info might help. (The real answer is "yes, but we don't know how messy it will be; it could be anything from cutting and splicing a few wires to designing a replacement for the control circuit.")

Comment: Can you post close-ups of the fan wiring at least?  And yes, a make and model would be helpful too